# Как провести автоматическое тестирование чат-ботов в мессенджерах?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, тестирование

Необходимо разработать систему, которая бы автоматически проверяла чат-ботов в разных мессенджерах(VK, Telegram, Facebook) и отображала найденные ошибки.

Comment: В чём проблема? Вы можете использовать обычные unit-тесты, которые можно улучшить, имитируя ответ сервера ([responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) например).

Comment: А если необходимо проверить 50+ ботов?

Comment: Делать +100500 тестов, покрывающее все нюансы